# Complex Inner Product and Orthogonalization

Tags: symbolic

```
Orthogonalize[{E^x, E^(w^1*x), E^(w^2*x), E^(w^3*x)}, 
  Integrate[#1 *Conjugate[#2], {x, -Pi, Pi}] &]
```

I am trying to orthogonalize the first 4 expression using my own custom inner product which is the integral of F(x)[G(x)]* from -pi to pi.  I want the second argument of the product (G(x)) to be the complex conjugate but I cannot figure out how to do that.
Any tips?

Comment: At a minimum try `E^x` instead of `e^x`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I changed it but it still seems to error out due to the integration.

Comment: Next step. What is the value of `w`? Is it a complex number? Also, what is the error message?

Comment: I changed some things and it is no longer erroring but instead giving me a long answer.  Should Mathematica be displaying Conjugate[i] instead of -i?

Comment: Try replacing `i` with `I` if you want $\sqrt{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the inner-product function needs to be linear in the second argument, meaning you need to reverse the order of the parameters in your inner-product function. If you set `w=a+I*b` and reverse your inner-product function:

```
F = Integrate[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[#1]]*#2, {x, -Pi, Pi}] &
```

then this simplified example works:

```
S = Orthogonalize[{E^x, E^(w^1*x)}, F]
```

Test:

```
F[S[[1]], S[[1]]]
(* 1 *)
F[S[[1]], S[[2]]]
(* 0 *)
```

With your four terms it should work too, but will take a long time.

Keep in mind that the manual on `Orthogonalize` says that "The $e_i$ can be any expressions for which $f$ always yields real results." Your example does not satisfy this condition (some of the overlap integrals are complex-valued); what I wrote above about linearity in the second argument may or may not work properly.

Comment: There is an example u = Orthogonalize[RandomComplex[1 + I, {4, 4}]] in the help.

Comment: Look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space concerning linearity in the second argument. This property is not required.

Comment: Seem to work, thanks!

Comment: @user64494 you're correct about the mathematical definitions (wiki link); however this is not how it's implemented in Mathematica. When I define `F = Integrate[#1*ComplexExpand[Conjugate[#2]], {x, -Pi, Pi}] &` to make the inner-product function linear in the first argument, as initially proposed, then the result is incorrect in the sense that `F[S[[1]], S[[2]]]` does not give zero.

Comment: Upgrade your math. BTW, Maple produces answer to the original  question with $w=(-1)^{\frac 1 4}$ in approximately 400 seconds.